# ¿Por qué router-outlet funciona o no funciona dependiendo de su localización en el código?

Tags: angular, routing

Dado el **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</body>
</html>
```

y la componente **app-navbar**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-list">
      <li class="navbar-item">
        <a routerLink="/inicio" routerLinkActive="active" class="navbar-link">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-item">
        <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" class="navbar-link">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

¿por qué si el router-outlet lo pongo en el index.html inmediatamente después del app-navbar consigo que se cambie de ruta pero no que se muestre el contenido de la componente a la que navegamos?

Teóricamente, router-outlet actúa como marco para mostrar lo que el routerLink activo contenga. Entonces, siempre que el router-outlet esté por encima de los routerLink en el árbol de parentesco **debería mostrar el contenido de sus hijos unidos por routerLink**.

En nuestro caso, router-outlet es padre de /inicio y /login si lo escribimos en app-navbar y es abuelo de ambos si lo escribimos en index.html. Así pues, debería mostrar el contenido del que esté activo de los dos tanto desde index.html como desde app-navbar. ¿Por qué desde index.html no muestra nada a pesar de cambiar de ruta?

Adjunto la hoja **app-routing**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'inicio', component: InicioComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'inicio'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: ¿`app-navbar` es el componente raíz de la aplicación?

Comment: efectivamente, app-navbar es el componente raíz

Comment: En el ejemplo que muestras el enrutador raíz tiene las rutas `/inicio` y `/login`, y el `router-outlet` mostrará el contenido de esas rutas si se encuentra también en la raíz de la aplicación, o sea dentro del `app-navbar`.  La jerarquía del router outlet no funciona igual que la de los elementos html, no por estar más arriba se convierte en padre/abuelo..., debe estar ubicado en la posición correcta para reflejar las rutas de su enrutador asociado.

Comment: Si no entendí mal, router-outlet suma a la ruta en la que se encuentra el valor de ruta (path) definido en el app-routing. En el ejemplo funcional, obtenemos "/" + "inicio" = "/inicio", que es la ruta correcta. En el caso no funcional (sacando router-outlet fuera de app-navbar) obtenemos "../" + "inicio" = "../inicio", lo cual significa que estamos navegando fuera de la raíz para poner allí la componente inicio (incorrecto totalmente). ¿Van por ahí los tiros?

Comment: Buena forma de verlo. Sí, ese es el comportamiento. Puedes terminar de probarlo creando rutas hijas y anidando los `router-outlet` y verás el mismo comportamiento que describes.